Blazor 8.0 SSR: Issue with model binding complex object with child collection
In my Blazor app with no client-side interactivity, I have the following complex object:
public class Invoice
{
    [Required]
    public string? Customer { get; set; }

    public List<InvoiceLine> Lines { get; set; } = [];
}

public class InvoiceLine
{
    [Required]
    public string? Item { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

My invoice page component looks as follows:
@page "/Sales/Invoice"
@inject ILogger<InvoicePage> Logger

<PageTitle>Invoice</PageTitle>
<h1>Invoice</h1>

<EditForm Model="Invoice" OnValidSubmit="Submit" FormName="InvoiceForm">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="offset-2 col-4">
            <ValidationSummary Model="Invoice" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label for="Invoice.Customer" class="col-2 col-form-label text-end">Customer</label>
        <div class="col-4">
            <InputText @bind-Value="Invoice.Customer" class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Invoice.Customer)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-6">
            <table id="Lines" class="table table-bordered mt-2">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Invoice.Lines.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var line = Invoice.Lines[i];
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <InputText @bind-Value="line.Item" class="form-control" name="@($"Invoice.Lines[{i}].Item")" />
                                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => line.Item)" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <InputNumber @bind-Value="line.Amount" class="form-control" name="@($"Invoice.Lines[{i}].Amount")" />
                                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => line.Amount)" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Remove line</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Add line</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="offset-2 col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "InvoiceForm")]
    public Invoice? Invoice { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Invoice ??= new();
        Logger.LogInformation("Invoice.Lines = {Lines}", Invoice.Lines);
    }

    private void Submit()
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Form successfully submitted");
    }
}

Now, Invoice.Lines becomes null if I submit the form without entering anything, and consequently, null reference execption is thrown at for loop (Log prints 'Invoice.Lines = null'). How come?
The exception goes away if I initialize Invoice.Lines with some line
Invoice ??= new() { Lines = [new InvoiceLine()] };

But, I expect user can delete lines and may even try to submit a form without any line.
I can check if Invoice.Lines is null before for loop, but this will be extra code, given that
I already initialized Invoice.Lines in Invoice class to be empty list.
UPDATE
The issue won't resolve even if I initialize Invoice property at the declaration:
[SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "InvoiceForm")]
public Invoice Invoice { get; set; } = new();

